# Return list of accessible top line folders in Firebase Storage, for public and authenticated users

Tags: firebase-storage, firebase-security

As per my question:

I have a folder (prefix) structure in Firebase Storage like so:

```
--FBTEST
  --privateFiles
    --folder1
    --folder2
    --folder3
  --publicFiles
    --folder1
    --folder2
    --folder3
```

with secure rules currently set like so:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/<BUCKET>/o {
    match /FBTEST/privateFiles/{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
    match /FBTEST/publicFiles/{allPaths=**} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

I would like make it possible, using `listAll()` for users (authenticated and anonymous) to be able to return a list of the top line folders that are accessible to them. Thus for authenticated users a list of `["privateFiles","publicFiles"]` could be returned, and for anonymous users `["publicFiles"]`. It does not appear possible, by setting rules on `FBTEST`, to do this with the way that rules cascade down? Other suggestions too are welcome.